# return nth value in ranked numeric field using Qlikview

Tags: min, rank, qlikview

I want to return the nth value in a numeric field in a Qlikview chart. The field is not sorted in the load. I want n to be an expression.

I have tried using `min(FieldName, round(expression))` but the offest value is not recognised and the 1st minimum value is returned.

Is there a way round this that allows me to use an expression to determine the value of n?

Comment: Have you tried using an `aggr()` in your `round()` expression?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Rank function. It specifically works on expressions and you can also specify how the rank behaves (min, max, avg).

```
rank([ total ] expression [ , mode [, format ] ])
```

There are also variants like HRank and VRank but they work in specific charts.

Then simply pick the nth value from the rank like

```
pick(n, rank())
```

Comment: but how do I return the nth value of that ranked expression?

Comment: wrap it around a pick function like pick(n, rank()).